# "cordova build android" fails with "no installed build tools found"

Tags: android, cordova

I have looked EVERYWHERE for the solution to this.

[Ionic Cordova Build Android No installed build tools found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54447081/ionic-cordova-build-android-no-installed-build-tools-found) did not work

[cordova build android failed with exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74952540/cordova-build-android-failed-with-exception) was a ridiculous non-answer. OF COURSE Android Studio is installed!!!

[Android studio- "SDK tools directory is missing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28789556/android-studio-sdk-tools-directory-is-missing) I did this.  The $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools folder now exists, but that didn't solve my problem.

I tried the advice given here: [Ionic Cordova Build Android No installed build tools found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54447081/ionic-cordova-build-android-no-installed-build-tools-found) and all I get when I run `sdkmanager packages "build-tools;30.0.3"` is "failed to find package 'packages'" from the SDK Manager.

I looked here: [Android SDK Manager does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45748183/android-sdk-manager-does-not-exist) and installed ALL the stuff they said to install -- including the obsolete packages.  And still no luck.

Here's my path:
`/opt/homebrew/bin:/Users/lmacneill/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin:/Users/lmacneill/.sdkman/candidates/gradle/current/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/lmacneill/CordovaProjects/gamapp/node_modules/.bin:/Users/lmacneill/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/lmacneill/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools:/Users/lmacneill/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools`

Here's my Android Studio SDK Platforms screen:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2e5YI.png

And here's my Android Studio SDK Tools screen:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/btLIR.png

(Unrelated to this post, but very weird -- it told me I needed 10 reputation to post images, yet I have 661 reputation.  Why did it do that?  Hence the *link* to my images instead of the actual images.)

**SO WHY CAN THE TOOLS NOT BE FOUND?!!!!!!**. I've done EVERYTHING that EVERYONE has suggested, and STILL IT DOESN'T WORK!!!!

This is ridiculous!!!!  Surely someone must know the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well...  I **FINALLY** figured it out...

In the `$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/build-tools` folder, there was a `33.0.2` folder.  So in my .zshrc file, instead of adding `$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/build-tools` to the path, I needed to add `$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/build-tools/33.0.2` to the path.

Then `cordova build android` **FINALLY** worked!!!

BTW, I figured this out when I finally got sdkmanager to install the build-tools;30.0.3 -- you have to use `sdkmanager "build-tools;30.0.3"` command, *NOT* the `sdkmanager packages "build-tools;30.0.3"` command.  Maybe the command with the 'packages' bit worked for an older version of sdkmanager?  But it definitely doesn't work now.  Anyway, once I saw that it had created a new folder in $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/build-tools, I finally realized that exporting only $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/build-tools in the path wasn't enough.  You have to include the version folder in there as well.

**ANDROID!!!  Y'ALL SHOULD MAKE THIS EASIER!!!!**  INSTALLING ANDROID STUDIO SHOULD DO ALL OF THIS STUFF AUTOMATICALLY!!!!!

Comment: Yeah, this sucks